# The solution of Mawhin problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

In my lecture on ODE the following problem was proposed:

> **Mawhin problem**:
>
> Find a periodic function $p(t)$ such that the ODE $x'' + \sin(x) = p(t) + n$ has all its solutions non-bounded for all $n \neq 0$.

I guess there does not exist a solution to this problem yet, but are there any partial results on it?

Comment: Shouldn't that be **Mawhin** problem, after Jean Mawhin?

Comment: Right @HansEngler, thing is I'm reading someone else notes. But I read on the guy, it is Mawhin indeed, thank you